# docker - jwilder/nginx-proxy, container create issue

Tags: docker, jwilder-nginx-proxy

After updating dockeron Version 18.03.0-ce-win59 (16762), jwilder/nginx-proxy doesn't running.

i'm currently working on WINDOWS 10 and DOCKER VERSION:18.03.0-ce-win59 (16762).
And Here is my docker Compose file.

```
version: "3.1"

services:

  #docker run -d -p 80:80 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock jwilder/nginx-proxy  
  proxy-server:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    container_name: proxy-server
    ports: 
      - 80:80
    volumes: 
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock
    networks:
      - development_network
```

and the error is:

> ERROR: for proxy-server  Cannot create container for service
>   proxy-server: b'Mount denied:\nThe source path
>   "\\var\\run\\docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock"\nis not a valid
>   Windows path' ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

Comment: @thomasleveil, their is any update on this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a workaround, I created .env file in the same directory with docker compose yaml file and I included this line in the file:

COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1

https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1829#issuecomment-376328022

Comment: I had the same issue and adding COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1 to my .env file works as a temp fix

Answer (score -1):

Can you try removing volumes section or give a location as per your host windows machine.

`/var/run/docker.sock` location will not be present in your windows system.

either use `.:/tmp/docker.sock` or specify something like `d:/test:/tmp/docker.sock` where `test` folder should exist in the d drive.

Comment: removing volumes section doesn't work and i am not sure about the location. the volume section says /var/run/docker.sock but i don't sure where is the path in windows.

Comment: `/var/run/docker.sock` will not be present in your windows system

Comment: So is their any solution?

Comment: either use `.:/tmp/docker.sock` or specify something like `d:/test:/tmp/docker.sock` where `test` folder should exist in the d drive

Comment: also you can refer this - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stevelasker/2016/06/14/configuring-docker-for-windows-volumes/